# What kind of tarot is used in Persona 5?

Tags: persona-5

I'm currently replaying P5 with my SO and she likes all that tarot stuff. And as you know, tarot cards are an element within the game.

But my SO was telling me that some cards seem right, but others seem completely created for the game or at least modified.

I know there are load of different varieties of tarot so is the Tarot used in P5 a real variety of Tarot or was it created for the game (and just inspired by Tarot in general?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a mashup, or at least not based on any single variety. According to [Gamerant](https://gamerant.com/persona-5-royals-atypical-arcana-faith-consultant/):

> The original Persona 5 and the rest of the base Persona series' base
> their major arcana's numbering, symbolism, and confidants on the
> standard, Rider Tarot Deck. The Consultant, or Councilor, represented
> by Takuto Maruki, is drawn from the Spanish, Esoterico Tarot Deck

The other new arcana is Faith which, at least according to [fandom](https://megamitensei.fandom.com/wiki/Faith_Arcana):

> Faith is not found in standard tarot decks. The Faith Arcana is
> present in the Visconti-Sforza tarot deck.